# Work Order Line Item not being inserted in test class

Tags: unit-test, dml, work-order

I have a piece of code in my apex class which queries a work order with the corresponding Case ID.

I have written the corresponding test method for this class, as follows:

```
Case c = new Case();
insert c;
WorkOrder wrkOrdr = new WorkOrder(Case = c);
insert wrkOrdr;
WorkOrderLineItem wrkOrdrLineItm= new WorkOrderLineItem(WorkOrder = wrkOrdr);
insert wrkOrdrLineItm;
```

However, `insert wrkOrdrLineItm` throws an Exception:

> System.DmlException: Insert failed.
>
> First exception on row 0; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: []

How can I correct my code to create a work order line item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is how you set the parent:

```
new WorkOrderLineItem(WorkOrder = wrkOrdr);
```

When you set `WorkOrder`, you are using a fairly niche feature: [Creating Parent and Child Records in a Single Statement Using Foreign Keys](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_foreign_keys.htm)

The API Name of the field is `WorkOrderId`. The standard way to set a reference is by Id. So instead use:

```
new WorkOrderLineItem(WorkOrderId = wrkOrdr.Id);
```